# VBA Dictionary.exists inside a For Each loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code and what i am trying to do basically i want to do a dictionary.exists function inside a For Each loop. but for some reason it's not working.

```
Sub TEST()

Dim oFso As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim oFldr As Object
Dim pointctr As Integer
Dim cadfilename As String
Dim fileDict As Object
Dim ext As String

    Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFldr = oFso.getfolder(RB.Range("D4").Value & "\" & CADdoss)
    Set fileDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'I am adding some keys in the dictionary based on the value of a cell in the C Column
    For i = 1 to 23
            If RB.Range("C" & i).value = True then
                filedict.Add RB.Range("D" & i).value,""
            End If
    Next i


    ' then i am doing a for each loop inside a folder to know if the values from
    ' the dictionary matches some filenames inside the folder
    For Each oFile In oFldr.Files
        pointctr = InStrRev(oFile.name, ".")
        cadfilename = Left(oFile.name, pointctr - 1)

        if filedict.exists(cadfilename) then
            debug.print cadfilename
        end if

    Next
```

What i am trying to do is when the oFile name exist in the dictionary it will debug.print
the name.

Right now it only debug.prints one name in the loop.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Is `RB` a worksheet object?

Comment: `RB.Range("C" & i).value = True` might be the cause of the issue. I've had trouble doing untyped comparisons in my own projects, especially with the `Variant` type that comes from the `Range.Value` property. I suggest always doing a conversion before doing comparisons with `Variant` values. `CBool(RB.Range("C" & i).Value) = True`

Comment: Hello! yes RB is a worksheet..

Comment: i have check the dictionary and the keys are there .. so the dictionary add function is working.. the problem is when I try to run it inside the for each loop .. when i run it only debug.prints 1 instance of the files that match .

Comment: The dictionary is by default case sensitive. To make it case insensitive, use `fileDict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare` right below the `Set...` line.

Comment: Avoid trailing spaces with Trim `fileDict.Add Trim(RB.Range("D" & i).Value),""` and not the problem but you can  use `cadfilename = oFso.getBaseName(oFile.Name)` to remove the extension.

Comment: it worked! thank you for the kind advices :) basically the compare mode made the difference. and thank you also for the getbasename advice :) you are all the best!